# UITableViewCell, set dynamic height w/ multiple labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell with two labels in it. One label contains a short definition for a word, and the other contains a longer definition that is only shown when the cell is selected. The lengths of the short definitions differentiate between words and cells, so setting an explicit height for the cell sometimes cuts off part of the definition. The problem is, if I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension, the cell sets its height to one that is appropriate for the longer definition label, even though the longer definition label is hidden at this time. This is leaving a lot of white space in the cell. When the cell is tapped, the longer definition label appears, the shorter one disappears, and the cell expands properly. How can I set dynamic heights for my cells that will work with both the shorter and longer labels so I can remove this additional white space when it isn't needed?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if currentRow == indexPath.row {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return 150.0
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The custom cell I am using**

The definitionLabel is hidden until the cell is touched in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I need the cell to conform to heights for both the definitionLabel and the quickDefinitionLabel at different times.

```
class ListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var definitionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var quickDefinitionLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        definitionLabel.hidden = true
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.wordLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        definitionLabel.hidden = true
        quickDefinitionLabel.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: use :
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = "HEIGHT OF CELL IN UI"
       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Answer (score 0):

Under iOS 8 and autolayout, you simply need two lines of code in your `ViewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

The first number should be your smallest size.

You don't need the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method at all.

Comment: I've tried this before, and it doesn't fix the problem for me unfortunately. I mean it works as it's supposed to, but doesn't fix my problem of excess whitespace. My issue is that I have a label that is hidden until the cell is touched. In most cases the label contains a lot of text, so it's very tall. The cells are still conforming to the height of that label even though it is hidden when the cells first appear. This is leaving me with a lot of empty white space, because the cell is conforming to a hidden label. That is why I was using heightForRowAtIndexPath. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I think I'd set the height of the hidden label to 0 and move it up far enough that it doesn't affect row height, then move it back down, restore the label height, and unhide it when I wanted to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around where I don't set the long definition text until the cell is selected...It clears up the white space issue and seems to work for what I want it to work for.